# Class Property is undefined after setted by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to set a Class property by ajax. That code works for me:

```
class SweetCalendar{
    constructor(){
        this.getEmployees();
    }
    
    getEmployees(){
        let url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/api/v1/employeelist/';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            context: this,
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                this.employees = result;
            },
            timeout: 120000,
        });
    }
```

When I test the class with

```
var a = new SweetCalendar()
console.log(a.employees)
```

I receive the expected array of employees. Now I want to iterate over this property with the test-function within the class:

```
class SweetCalendar{
    constructor(){
        this.getEmployees();
    }

test(){
for(i of this.employees){
            console.log(i)
        }
}
    
    getEmployees(){
        let url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/api/v1/employeelist/';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            context: this,
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                this.employees = result;
            },
            timeout: 120000,
        });
    }

var a = new SweetCalendar();
a.test();
```

This doesn't work. This.employees is undefined. I assume this is due to the asynchronus ajax but i dont know how to solve this. Have anybody faced this problem as well before?

Comment: After initialization. edited my question

Comment: The `success: function (result, status, xhr) {` means that the `this` inside it no longer refers to the instance, use an arrow function instead